# Ignore 'undefined name' for certain global keywords w/ sublimelinter + flake8

Tags: sublimetext, sublimelinter, flake8

Using a bit of an unusual language, processing-py, which is a sort of python wrapper around the java processing language.

processing-py introduces many global keywords that don't need to be imported. These include functions names like loadPixels() and global variables (constants?) like 'width' (width of screen).

Sublimelinter + flake8 correctly raises F821 undefined name for these. It's not convenient to #noqa, I might as well just turn the linter off at that point. I'd also like to see when I am *actually* introducing a bogus keyword, such as typoing loadPixels() (good) as laodPixels() (bad).

So is there a way to add a list of exceptions for F821, or otherwise extend the dictionary of known keywords?

I'm also using a custom thTheme with the list of keywords, as part of the processing-py-sublime package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you ever solved your problem, but if you use SublimePythonIDE with SublimeText3, you can add a list of exceptions in either the plugin's User settings or Project settings:

In User settings, add:

`"pyflakes_ignore": ["background", "ellipse", "fill", "size" ... ]`

In Project settings, add to 'settings' object:

```
{
    "settings": {
        // Ignoring for Processing.py projects
        "pyflakes_ignore": ["background",
                            "ellipse",
                            "fill",
                            "size"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for taking a crack at this. I installed SublimePythonIDE (using ST3) and tried adding those settings at both the SublimePythonIDE user settings file, and in project settings file inside a settings object, and neither seemed to do anything :(

Can you find any documentation for this setting somewhere? I tried and failed. Found one gist that referenced the setting and that's about it.

Here are my linter versions if helpful: int tools versions:
- Python Flake8 Lint: 2.4.3
- pep8: 1.7.0
- flake8: 2.5.2
- pyflakes: 1.0.0

Have a feeling may be some misconfiguration on my side

Comment: Hmm. It could be that SublimeLinter is taking over linting (SublimePythonIDE provides its own linting and the setting above corresponds to that). Try disabling SublimeLinter configs for python (e.g. flake8) in your project or user settings.

I'm doing pretty much what you set out to do, i.e. using ST3 for processing.py, so it should work in some combination for you :)


FYI if you do get it working, I have a gist with the complete (I think) keyword list here that you can use:
https://gist.github.com/riverfr0zen/9fe49ce07efb7646e7f8a7acff7fbe9f

Comment: Ah yep, that was totally it. SublimeLinter was in charge, once I removed it I was able to add those ignores. Unfortunately I use SublimeLinter for javascript in other projects, so I'll have to see if maybe I can disable it for just this project. But your answer works so accepting it, thanks! Cool to know someone else is doing the st3/processing.py thing too. Thanks for the gist.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to remove SublimeLinter. You can disable specific linters in Project settings by adding "disable: true" to the linter settings. I'm glad that you found the other way below though--I had originally started out looking for a solution like that in SublimeLinter, so it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted the other user's answer, but figured out another way to do this that was more in-line with my current work flow.

I was using Sublime Linter + Python Flake8 Lint package.

Python Flake8 Lint has a setting called "builtins" which is meant for built-in python language keywords I guess. You can set this at the project level (I do all my pyprocessing mostly in one big sublime project).

yourpyprocessingproject.sublime-project:

```
"settings": {
    "flake8lint": {
      "builtins": [
            "draw",
            "exit",
            "loop",
            "noLoop"
            etc...
            ]
    }
}
```

And that did the trick. Use the gist in the accepted answer to get a full list of keywords.